# Make sure the spacing of a macro for a binary operator

Tags: math-mode, macros, spacing

I define a macro as follows:

```
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{{#1}^{\sharp}}
```

But I realize that `$a \abs{\sqcup} b$` is not exactly same as `$a \sqcup^\sharp b$`: The first one does not leave enough space between the operator and the operands.

Does anyone know how to amend the macro to make it a real binary operator in terms of spacing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you define

```
\newcommand\abs[1]{#1^\sharp}
```

the spacing will be inherited by the nature of `#1`; so

```
\abs{\sqcup}
```

will be spaced as a binary operator and

```
\abs{=}
```

will be spaced as a binary relation.

With you definition you get `{\sqcup}^{\sharp}` that's treated as an ordinary symbol.

### Some detail

When one tries the input `$a+^{\sharp}b^2\showlists$`, the `.log` file will report

```
### math mode entered at line <line number>
\mathord
.\fam1 a
\mathbin
.\fam0 +
^\fam1 ]
\mathord
.\fam1 b
^\fam0 2
```

The `\mathord` and `\mathbin` lines tell what type of math atom TeX is analyzing. Every atom has three fields: the *nucleus* (represented by `.`), the *superscript* (represented by `^`) and the *subscript* (represented by `_`).

Since `+` is defined to be a `\mathbin` atom, such type is reported. This atom has as nucleus the character `+` taken from family 0, and a superscript taken from family 1 (`cmsy10` font in the default setting, where the slot usually occupied by `]` has the "sharp" symbol).

If instead we say `$a{+}^{\sharp}b\showlists$`, the response is

```
### math mode entered at line <line number>
\mathord
.\fam1 a
\mathord
.\mathbin
..\fam0 +
^\fam1 ]
\mathord
.\fam1 b
```

The braces around a subformula tell TeX to treat the whole subformula as a `\mathord` atom; this atom has a nucleus formed by a `\mathbin` atom (at an inner level, represented by the two periods `..`), but this would have consequences only for the typesetting of the subformula, not with respect to the "outer" level. The braced `\mathord` atom has a superscript atom as before.

This is only the first step in typesetting a formula. When TeX has determined all the atoms it has to typeset, it applies its rules about spacing; for example 
it inserts a medium space between `\mathord` and `\mathbin` atoms (I'll skip over some subtlety), but it *never* inserts spaces between two `\mathord` atoms (unless, of course, such a space has been explicitly specified by the user).

Note that it's the same as with `\sqcup` instead of `+`, since also this symbol is declared as a `\mathbin` atom.

Answer (score 11):

You can force it to be a bin atom using `\mathbin`:

```
 \newcommand{\abs}[1]{\mathbin{{#1}^{\sharp}}}
```