# Incorrect spacing when placing binary operator in macro

Tags: math-mode, macros, spacing, color

I have macros of the form

```
\newcommand{\typo}[1]{{\color{red}#1}}% for pointing out that there is a typo
```

When I use this command in mathmode though, it creates incorrect spacing with binary operators (`$A\otimes B$` versus `$A\typo{\otimes}B$`).

I suspect this is a consequence of writing `\otimes` within `{...}` (see [Make sure the spacing of a macro for a binary operator](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49250/make-sure-the-spacing-of-a-macro-for-a-binary-operator?rq=1)), but `{...}` is necessary to keep the color contained. I could fix this issue by replacing `$A\typo{\otimes}B$` with  `$A\mathbin{\typo{\otimes}}B$`.

But is there a way to fix *the definition of the macro `\typo`*, so that `$A\typo{\otimes}B$` will produce the same spacing as `$A\otimes B$`?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\typo}[1]{{\color{red}#1}}% for pointing out that there is a typo

\begin{document} 

Compare $A\otimes B$ with $A\typo{\otimes}B$ with $A\mathbin{\typo{\otimes}}B$.

The first and third have correct spacing; the middle does not.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

a `\begingroup` group does not affect spacing in the same way.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\typo}[1]{\begingroup\color{red}#1\endgroup}% for pointing out that there is a typo

\begin{document} 

Compare $A\otimes B$ with $A\typo{\otimes}B$ with $A\mathbin{\typo{\otimes}}B$.

The first and third have correct spacing; the middle does not.

\end{document}
```

Of if you use the next version of `(x)color` already available if you use `pdflatex-dev` rather than `pdflatex` in texlive you can use `\mathcolor` which uses a definition based on this idea (but handling superscripts in a better way)

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\typo}[1]{\mathcolor{red}{#1}}% for pointing out that there is a typo

\begin{document} 

Compare $A\otimes B$ with $A\typo{\otimes}B$ with $A\mathbin{\typo{\otimes}}B$.

The first and third have correct spacing; the middle does not.

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\begingroup ... \endgroup` seems to be exactly what I was looking for, thank you! (The second solution does not work for me, because I do want to use `\typo` in non-math mode as well. -- or would I still be able to do so??)

Comment: @Anna How about `\newcommand{\typo}[1]{\csname\ifmmode math\else text\fi color\endcsname{red}{#1}}` ?

Comment: @UlrichDiez, I don't know how to parse your solution, sorry! I see that your snippet is checking whether I am or am not in mathmode. What's `\csname`? What is the advantage of your solution over the chosen solution?

Comment: @Anna csname "constructs" a command so Ulrich's code is essentially: " if in math \mathcolor{...} else \textcolor{...}` "  so it works in text and math and picks up the finer spacing details for subscripts that \mathcolor has (try `\typo{\sum}_0^n` )

Comment: @Anna I mean no disrespect, but let me point out that you are in the right place at TeX-LaTeX-StackExchange to do a "Search on TeX - LaTeX..." for "What does `\csname` do?" ;-) The search results, e.g., reveal the following question, to which, so it happens, I also wrote an answer as recently as December 16: [What exactly do \csname and \endcsname do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39380/) . ;-) I don't know if my answer is understandable, but there are other answers as well, and there is also the possibility to ask for clarification via comments/via follow-up questions/via chat. :-)

Comment: @Anna Regarding the fuzzy phrase "... whether **I** am or am not in mathmode...": When you work with TeX/LaTeX, it is very important to distance yourself from the machinery, so that if something doesn't work out, you can take it with humor. ;-))

Comment: @UlrichDiez I could indeed have looked up `\csname`; my bad. The more important part of my comment was: What is the advantage of your suggestion over the solution given by David Carlisle? :-)

Comment: @Anna The `\csname..\endcsname`-thing selects the command depending on the current typesetting-mode, avoiding typesetting non-math-material via `\mathcolor`. To be honest, I didn't know whether this is an advantage with the variant of `\mathcolor` from the latex-dev branch, the usage whereof is suggested by David Carlisle: I just recently learned that there is a new implementation of `\mathcolor` in the development pre-release of the LaTeX kernel and I did not yet find the time to study all the code carefully. ...

Comment: @Anna ...  So I asked in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60284478#60284478) whether there are drawbacks when using the command  `\mathcolor` for typesetting non-math-material as well. David Carlisle told me ["it (`\mathcolor`) doesn't work well in text and we will probably make it error just as \mathrm` gives an error if used outside math."](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60284513#60284513) So selecting the appropriate coloring-command depending on the current typesetting-mode seems an advantage to me. ...

Comment: @Anna ...  Besides this, in the past I saw various "home-brewed" definitions of `\mathcolor`. Definitely not all of those are suitable for typesetting material outside math-mode and with those a mechanism for selecting `\textcolor` if not in math-mode definitely is an advantage.  ;-)

Comment: @Anna Probably `\typo` should be robust and probably the argument can be omitted, i.e., `\csname @ifdefinable\endcsname{\typo}{\DeclareRobustCommand{\typo}{\csname\ifmmode math\else text\fi color\endcsname{red}}}`. Unnecessarily wasting memory for an unneeded macro argument - I don't know what I was thinking! :-)

Comment: @UlrichDiez Neither do I know what you were thinking :-D Thanks a lot for the in-depth explanation that goes far beyond my knowledge of it all. Hopefully, I'll appreciate your solution as much as it deserves eventually ;-)

Comment: @UlrichDiez Now, I suddenly get where your first comment came from: It was in reply to my own question, "_or would I still be able to do so??_". Took me only (!) a week to put 2 and 2 together. So: Please disregard my "_What is the advantage of your solution over the chosen solution?_".

Comment: @Anna  "Took me only (!) a week to put 2 and 2 together." So you are a lot faster than I usually am. :-)